Should multiple categorical embeddings be combined for a conditional GAN (cGAN)?
I'm trying to make a conditional GAN (cGAN) that generates YouTube thumbnails based on a title and a video category/genre.
It's not working whatsoever, not even close, and so I'm trying to go back to the basic fundamental questions about my architecture. Right now, what I did was make two embedding vectors, one for the title and one for the category, and then I just combine them and send them both to the generator & discriminator.
I'm wondering if this is okay to do? Or should I be passing them separately? I tried doing some research on it but it's a pretty niche problem.
